# "Чревато" и "чрево" — однокоренные слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Плохой поступок может быть чреват наказанием. И вот интересно, родственно ли слово "чреват" слову "чрево" и, если да, то как они связаны (вроде бы, по смыслу совершенно разные слова)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, слова родственные.
"Чрево" - желудок, внутренность, а "чреватый" в исходном значении - беременный. Связь очевидна. 
Из переносного употребления последнего развилось близкое к современному "чреватый" - влекущий последствия.
Негативная оценка этих последствий - это уже особенности употребления совсем недавнего времени.